# vb.net e ItextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itextsharp

Boas a todos, estou com um problema, através de uma lista estou a tentar criar um PDF, com o titulo e com o conteúdo.
Exemplo:

Titulo 1

Descrição titulo 1

O meu problema e que se tiver mais que um conteúdo para o Titulo 1 ele estará sempre a duplicar o titulo.

Exemplo:

Titulo 1

Descrição titulo 1

Titulo 1

Descrição titulo 1

E eu queria fazer o seguinte:

Titulo 1

Descrição titulo 1

Descrição Titulo 1.2

Titulo 2

Descrição titulo 2

Meu codigo:

```
        Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To administrador.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        'ADDTitle
        Dim FontTitle = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 11)
        Dim Titlechunk As New Chunk(gettitle(administrador.ListView1.Items(x).Text.Substring(4, 2)).ToString, FontTitle)
        Titlechunk.Font.SetStyle(FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim Titlepara As New Paragraph()
        Titlepara.Add(Titlechunk)
        Titlepara.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        PdfDoc.Add(Titlepara)

        'Descrição
        Dim FontDesc = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9)
        Dim phDesc As New Phrase()
        Dim Descchunk As New Chunk("  > " + administrador.ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text + " COM A QUANTIDADE NECESSÁRIA DE " + administrador.ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(2).Text + "UNIDADE(S)", FontDesc)
        phDesc.Add(Descchunk)
        Dim paraDesc As New Paragraph()
        paraDesc.Add(phDesc)
        PdfDoc.Add(paraDesc)

        PdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(" "))
    Next
```

Obrigado pela atenção :b

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você deseja. Poderia acrescentar mais detalhes na pergunta? Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais a respeito do site.

Comment: Boas, deixe ver se consigo explicar melhor, eu queria em PDF fazer títulos para categorias, mas se haver mais que uma categoria que mete-se tudo na mesma zona do titulo e não "duplica-se" sempre o titulo com a categoria.